# Parameter passing for ng-click throws parse error when using special character

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I want to display ajax content within the info Window but for some reason When I click on Marker ng-click function throws below error. However, if passing IDs containing only numbers, it works fine.

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 13-13 [@] in expression [getInfoFn(0AM@_255, $event)].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%2013-13%20%5B%40%5D&p2=getInfoFn(0AM%_255%2C%20%24event)
```

Below Plunker demonstrate the existing issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/dZ9vyOmrrPv7bbHrSIQs?p=preview

Comment: Well it seems like a String to me, so you must pass it on as a string as well:
`getInfoFn('" + info.id + "', $event)`. I added single quotes around `" + info.id + "`.

Comment: Thank you Artur.Yes this is the fix to my problem. You saved some hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the argument is String you need to put it between quotes for the final output.

So change this: `getInfoFn(" + info.id + ", $event)`

To this: `getInfoFn('" + info.id + "', $event)`

(I added single quotes around `" + info.id + "`)